# Can you help me to find the error?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4

What I´m expecting this code do is to obtain the Hash code of a file or a simple message and export it to a "txt" file. I must tell you that it's my first time writing code with classes, so I could make some mistakes.

I have written the following code but when I try to run it, the following error rises:

`File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1974, in pack_configure + self._options(cnf, kw))_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".45457360"`

I have tried for hours and what I could notice is that changing frameX.destroy() for frameX.pack_forget() let me to run the gui until parte2 and it's like if the gui restarted from the begining but the code keep continuing. Yes, it's someting strange so that's the why I can't explain it very well.

Please, if this question has been answered in another question, please, only answer but don't report me. The problem is that I can't find the cause of my problem so I can't find the solution.
Thanks to everyone.

```
from tkinter.filedialog import *
import hashlib

class programa:

    #------------------------------------------

    def parte1(self):
        global frame
        frame=Frame(ventana)
        frame.pack()
        Button(frame,text="Archivo",command=self.parte2_archivo).grid(row=0,column=0)
        Button(frame,text="Mensaje",command=self.parte2_mensaje).grid(row=0,column=1)
        ventana.mainloop()

    def parte2_archivo(self):
        frame.destroy()
        global Arch_to_HASH
        Arch_to_HASH=askopenfilename()
        Arch_to_HASH=open(Arch_to_HASH,"rb").read()
        self.parte4()

    def parte2_mensaje(self):
        frame.destroy()

        global frame2
        frame2=Frame(ventana)
        frame2.pack()
        Entry(frame2,textvariable=Men_to_HASH).pack()
        Button(frame2,text="Siguiente",command=self.parte3).pack()

    def parte3(self):
        frame2.destroy()    
        obj=Men_to_HASH.get()
        obj=obj.encode()
        self.parte4()


    def parte4(self):
        global frame3
        global listbox
        frame3=Frame(ventana)
        frame3.pack()
        listbox=Listbox(frame3)
        listbox.insert(END,"md5")       #0
        listbox.insert(END,"sha1")      #1
        listbox.insert(END,"sha224")    #2
        listbox.insert(END,"sha256")    #3
        listbox.insert(END,"sha384")    #4
        listbox.insert(END,"sha512")    #5
        Button(frame3,text="Siguiente",command=self.parte5)

    def parte5(self):
        if (listbox.curselection()==0):
            opcion="md5"
        elif (listbox.curselection()==1):
            opcion="sha1"
        elif (listbox.curselection()==2):
            opcion="sha224"
        elif (listbox.curselection()==3):
            opcion="sha256"
        elif (listbox.curselection()==4):
            opcion="sha384"
        elif (listbox.curselection()==5):
            opcion="sha512"
        else:
            pass

        hash=hashlib.new(opcion,obj).hexdigest()
        open("hash.txt","w").write(hash)






#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        global ventana
        global Men_to_HASH
        ventana=Tk()
        Men_to_HASH=StringVar()
        self.parte1()






programa()
```

**edit: The error is a foolness so I think this question is closed. Thank you for all the people who helped me**

Comment: give this question a better title please

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I didn't see my error so I could not write a good titke. The error was a foolness I made so I don't find reason to keep it open. I will change it anyway.

Comment: you can't delete it since it has answers, and I doubt it will be closed at this point, so a better title could help if someone does something similar in the future.  as it is, stackoverflow has way too many questions with titles like this.

Comment: I,ve changed it, if you could sugest me a title I would put it on the question

Comment: I'm not sure what line the error is coming from because you've omitted much of the traceback, but based on what I see, something like "Bad window pathname error when trying to pack tkinter frame" would be an improvement

Comment: The error I was talking about was solved by @marcin, I made  a mistake with a number and that was what made the error. That's why I wanted to close this question. Anyway, this code has errors, if you think that is better, I can upload the finished code, with the suggestions of marcin. Thanks for help me to made this question as full as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is because of this in parte4():

```
   frame3=Frame(ventana)
   frame.pack() #<---- this should be frame3.pack()
```

With this change, the code will execute. However, whether it actually does what you want it to do, is probably a topic for another question.

p.s. 
Also have a read about classes and `self`. Dont need to use `global` all the time to share variables between methods of a class. use `self`, e.g.

```
self.frame3=Frame(ventana)
self.frame3.pack()
```

Comment: Thank you, I made a mistake for "blind". And thank you for your recomendation, I will use the self method but, does it have any change that is not that global share the variable to all the code and 'self' only to the class???
Thank you very much.

Comment: You use self to have instance variable of a class scoped for the instance. Global are global for everything, which usually is not a good idea.

Comment: @cotuex Glad I could help. If this answer is satisfactory, accepting it would be appreciated. Thx